# No qtCreator in qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.1

Tags: c++, qt, compilation

I've downloaded and compiled successfully qt but there is no QtCreator, just designer, assistant + other dlls. Am I supposed to do something else additionally to compilation of this source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download Qt-creator. It isn't included in Qt sources.